# Trying to deploy laravel 8.82 on digitalocean but composer error

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu

i am trying to deploy a laravel project on my digitalocean server and below are the errors i am getting, tried everything i could but i keep getting this error

"Composer detected issues in your platform: Your Composer dependencies require a PHP version ">= 8.0.2"."

PHP version i am running on the server is php 8.1.1 and the laravel project is 8.82

i tried --ignore-platform-reqs but then i get a 500 internal error afterwards

Please help.

Thank you

Comment: `php --version`?

Comment: i did that and i get 8.1.1

Comment: try to `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: CLI version can be different that phpinfo() shows

Comment: `Your Composer dependencies require a PHP version ">= 8.0.2"` means composer is using a different PHP binary than what you think it is.  Run `which composer` and then use `php /path/to/composer install` and see if that works. If it does then it likely means you have two (or more) PHP versions on your server and composer is using the wrong one (one fix could be to edit your composer file and change the first line to use the correct php binary)

Comment: @apokryfos when i run the composer install i get a php deprecated and it fails

Comment: To clarify you get the same message when you run `php /path/to/composer install` ?

Comment: @apokryfos yes i get the same error when i run that as well